# How to remove mymodule configurations on uninstall

Tags: 8, configuration

I have created a custom module and created a yml file to create a menu

```
system.menu.custom_menu.yml

id: custom_menu
label: 'Custom menu'
description: 'Custom menu.'
langcode: en
locked: true
dependencies:
  - mymod
```

When I installed my module it creates the the custom menu. 
But then When I uninstall the module and try to install it again I get the following exception

```
exception 'Drupal\Core\Config\PreExistingConfigException' with message 'Configuration objects (system.menu.custom_menu) provided by mymod already exist in active configuration' in
/var/www/drupal8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/PreExistingConfigException.php:70
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there any way to remove my configuration (system.menu.custom_menu) from the configurations when I uninstall my module?

Comment: Similar problem? (unfortunately unanswered): http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164612/how-to-remove-a-configuration-object-from-active-config-in-drupal-8

Comment: Easy Install module is there to solve and avoid this issue completely https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_install

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The easiest way is to ensure that the config has a dependency on your module.

```
dependencies:
  module:
    - yourmodule
  enforced:
    module:
      - yourmodule
```

Then Drupal will automatically remove that configuration and also warn in the UI that it will be removed.

Note that this only works for new installations, it won't fix existing ones.

An alternative is to put the configuration in config/optional instead of config/install, then it will only be created if it doesn't exist yet and the dependencies are met.

Comment: I just observed on un-installing a module in d8, drupal cleans-up all the configuration. I had some configurations on config/install/module.settings.yml I installed the module, looked into config db table, I could see the configurations in the table, then I simply uninstalled the module re-check the config table and configurations are gone! Am I missing something here?

Comment: Looks like this approach doesn't work with Entity Reference fields at the moment.  I created a bug report: [Config entities removed in wrong order causes PDOException](https://www.drupal.org/node/2762381)

Comment: Any explanation for the "enforced" bit? I mean, a dependency is a dependency. Isn't its enforcement a given? Is that's what's necessary for the uninstall?

Comment: Normal dependencies are calculated by code. Just becaouse you define a node type doesn't mean that anything specifically depends on your module. Saving a config entity re-calculates dependencies and your module will not be in that list.. unless you explicitly add it as an enforced dependency.

Comment: "Note that this only works for new installations, it won't fix existing ones." - is there any manual SQL tweak that will fix this? I've tried `DELETE FROM config WHERE ...` and a `drush cr` after `pm-uninstall` but when I next `en`/`pm-uninstall`, the `enforced:` is still not respected. Is the dependency tree stored elsewhere?

Comment: I think the "problem" here was that I was trying this out with purely example data, whereas: (a) `ConfigDependencyManager::$data` only has entries that have a UUID (so `views.settings` isn't even present); and (b) `ConfigManager::findConfigEntityDependentsAsEntities()` filters out anything with an unrecognized config prefix (so if your module decides to set `views.foo` on Views' behalf, it won't be recognized). Basically: "'enforced:' only makes sense for config_entity" is the key, but I don't think that's necessarily clear.

Comment: This solution works for disabling parent modules when you have a sub-modules. Otherwise when using itself as a dependency you will not be able to re-enable your module.